# How to select 3rd 'a' tag in a list for RSpec test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, css-selectors, click, rspec-rails

How do I select a link in a list to click on for an rspec acceptance test. The code for the view is (in html):

```
%ul.exports
  %li.model
    .name
      Model 1
    .control
      link_to 'Export', export_model_path(:model1)
```

I've tried

```
(page.find("a")[:href] = "/admin/export/users").click
```

and the response is 'Capybara Ambiguous match'. I've also tried variations on

```
page.find(".exports li:nth-child(3) control a").click
```

and the response is 'unable to find css'. All the items in the list are identical except for the href value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've only got a single `a` tag in your Haml example, so I'm guessing your example is incomplete. If you want to retrieve a link by it's `href` value you could try this:

```
find(:xpath, "//a[@href='/admin/export/users']").click
```

Comment: awesome! that worked, thank you so much. I'll read up so I understand the solution you've offered.

Comment: Great! You can find more on XPath and Capybara [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#xpath-css-and-selectors) and more on finding [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#finding)